# PostGIS - 1.5 to 2.0 easy update

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, update

I have a PostGIS 1.5 database and want to update to 2.0. I read that because this is major release I have to follow the 'Hard update' procedure. However the spatial data I have is only test data so I can drop it.

If this is the case, is there easier procedure to update to 2.0 if I don't care about spatial data (I do care about non-spatial tables)?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you running?

Comment: It is 1.5.3 and I want to upgrade to 2.0.0

Comment: PostGIS version != Postgres version

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. It's Postgres 9.1.3

Comment: make a backup of your data first then do the 'hard update' managed to update without issue.

Comment: Yes, I know the 'hard update'. But I was thinking if I can omit the step of creating a new DB. Just do some drops to uninstall existing postgis and install new one to the same DB. Would that work?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about losing your postgis geometry columns etc, you can run the uninstall_postgis.sql  that is packaged with 1.5 (IT WILL DESTROY ALL POSTGIS DATA so be sure).  Then you can install PostGIS 2.0 without needing to restore.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Though I have went through hard upgrade already:].